# Verify and replace id to match a pattern in java?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I've a requirement where I'm getting a string that may or may not contain an `s` at the begining and then numbers that can be from 1 digit to 5 digits. Now, this string needs to be like the `s` and 5 digits (it cannot contain another letter), something like this:

`s1 -> s00001
s12 -> s00012
s123 -> s00123
s1234 -> s01234
s12345 -> s12345`

Because the s may or may not come, I need to check that too before adding the leading zeros.
This is what I got so far but is it there a better solution for this (maybe with regular expresions?

```
private String formatStoreNumber(String storeNumber) {
        if(storeNumber.contains("s")) {
            storeNumber = storeNumber.replace("s", "");
        }
        storeNumber = StringUtils.leftPad(storeNumber, 5, '0');
        storeNumber = "s" + storeNumber;
        return storeNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible for a string to contain more then one 's'?  (And therefore need more than on number replaced?)

Comment: @markspace no, it cannot

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression? Here's another, shorter way, still not using a regex: `"s" + new DecimalFormat("00000").format(Integer.parseInt(("s" + storeNumber).split("[s]+")[1]))`

Comment: @ernest_k the regex was an idea.. could you please explain me a little bit how your code works?

Comment: It splits the string on `s`, then formats the parsed integer using `00000`, which simply means that it prepends zeroes as necessary to match the length. `"s" + storeNumber` is done to take care of cases where `s` is omitted (but in case it was included, the split regex `[s]+` will split on any number of consecutive `s`... Well, I lied when I said it didn't use a regex :-)

Comment: @ernest_k could you please post that as an answer? I'll test that and set answered if it works. Thanks!

Comment: what about if string may be s3 or s4 or s2? then what should be output?  ans length of string must be 6? @user

Comment: @Deadpool output with s1 s2 or s3 should be `s00001` `s00002` and `s00003`

Comment: i believe below code solves your problem @Phoenix_uy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below solution :

```
private static String formatStoreNumber(String storeNumber) {
    String strWithoutS = storeNumber.replaceAll("S", "");
    String result = "S" + ("00000" + strWithoutS).substring(strWithoutS.length());
    return result;
}
```

Below are the input and respective output:

```
Input : S14666|  Output : S14666
Input : 1     |  Output : S00001
Input : 12    |  Output : S00012
Input : 123   |  Output : S00123
Input : 1234  |  Output : S01234
Input : 12345 |  Output : S12345
```